# How can I count the amount of relevant results in an observableArray for each filter?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm working on some functionality which is a derivative of the jsfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/0kbmchxe/9/, which was some great help given to me on a previous question.

As a next step I'm looking to extend this functionality to be able count the amount of existing results for each filter and bind these to the DOM.

I'd like these values to update as/when each filter is selected. So, for example, if 2 results matching the value 'white' exist when the full dataset is visible, I'd like to display a '2' next to the filter name, but then if another filter adjusts this value, I'd like for it to update accordingly.

I assume this is as easy as just storing the value in an observable, but I'm struggling on how to query the products array with values from the filters array.

I'm guessing I need to loop through the final array:

```
for(i = 0; i < self.filter().length; i++){

}
```

And query each value against the relevant filter:

```
var whiteCount,
    blackCount,
    blueCount;
if(self.filter()[i].color === "White"){
    whiteCount += 1;
} else if (self.filter()[i].color === "Black") {
    blackCount += 1;
} else if (self.filter()[i].color === "Blue"){
    blueCount += 1;
}
```

And then turn the variable into an observable which would be bound to the DOM:

```
whiteCount: ko.observable(whiteCount); //and so on
```

I get the feeling I'm either really close to cracking this, or I could be miles away from the best solution. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to use a computed observable

```
var child = this;
        this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
        this.color = ko.observable(data.color || undefined);
        this.price = ko.observable(data.price || undefined)
        this.checked = ko.observable(false);
        this.colorCount = ko.computed(function(){
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.filter(),function(item){
                return item.color == child.color();
            }).length;
        });
```

and in your mark up

```
<label data-bind="text: color, attr: { for: 'color' + id }"></label>
            <i data-bind="text:colorCount"></i>
```

you have to do something similar for the price filter, the fiddle can be found here 
http://jsfiddle.net/0kbmchxe/10/

Comment: Turns out I was miles away from the best solution. That works really well, thank you for your help.